# How to update the "updater"? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a program that consists of two programs: Updater and WorkMaker.
Whenever there is an update for WorkMaker - Updater kills it, downloads updates, and runs it again.
But say I came up with new Updater program.
How do I update it? Through WorkMaker? Through the third program?
Thanks.

Comment: how do you deploy your setup? what installer are you using?

Comment: Are you using any third party tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution IMHO is:

- At the moment was requested update `MainProgram` downloads `Updater`, along with updates, after launches `Updater`.
- Updater closes `MainProgram`, makes update and relaunch `MainProgram`, or simply exit.

In this way you have flexible way to update your program (`MainProgram`), but also `Updater` itself, when its required.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how far along your application's architecture is, but as a total replacement for "Updater" have you considered [using ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996413.aspx) for managing the deployment of "WorkMaker"?

It will ensure that it's running the latest patch on startup. If the application is a long running one, then you can also [manually kick off upgrades too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404263.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I use a similar setup to run our msi and msp files when necessary.  The solution consists of a small executable that loads a worker DLL in a second AppDomain using [Shadow Copying](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279.aspx).  The executable is so simple that I've never needed to change it.  However, I can now easily patch my worker DLL as I please since it's not locked in its original location on disk.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your updater dowload the update, run it with some parameters and have the new updater delete the original.

You could also have WorkMaker act as the updater for your Updater program.