# Updating an Updater

Tags: delphi

I have several small standalone programs that have an update. I have one updater, that can update them (there is no installer for the projects needed, it simply replaces the files).

But how do I update the updater itself? I see three solutions on my own, but what would be the best way?

1) [How to update "updater"? (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894243/how-to-update-updater-c)
The problem here is, i dont want to have in each of my small programs the updater included; another problem would be, that the updater can patch all applications, but in some cases a person gets one application and should not be aware of the others.

2) Downloading a second updater with the first one, starting the new updater, deleting first and renaming itself to match old shortcuts. Best would be, if its possible to have do a selfreplace (deleting itself when the new file is loaded and replace the old one by itself)

3) Creating a launcher for the updater, the launcher will never be updated, but can replace the updater. Seems a bit overkill to me.

All 3 solutions should work more or less, but maybe there is an easier way/ cleaner solution.

Comment: What kind of applications is the updater updating? Is it a desktop application(s) that end-users install? Are these background services and/or web applications on your company's internal servers? Are these applications installed on users' computers within your company? The reason I ask is because there are very easy solutions for cases in the spectrum of the latter two examples.

Comment: You have to stop somewhere. Once you write an updater for the updater, how do you update the updater updater? Make your updater work first time you release it.

Comment: Indeed, I'm writing an "Update launcher" in a way which is independent of the version and doesn't ever need to get updated. Its sole purpose is to download the latest version's installer from our web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing any additional info, the absolute easiest and fastest way I can think of (if all of the computers that have these applications are on the same network) is to simply write a batch file that checks for the existence of each application on the local machine, and if it finds it, it pulls an "update" batch file for that application from a central location and runs it (then continue on for the other applications).

Something like this:

```
...

SET CentralLoc=\\CentralServer\Updates

...

IF EXIST C:\CompanyApplications\Application1 (  
    COPY %CentralLoc%\UpdateApplication1.bat .\
    call .\UpdateApplication1.bat
)

...
```

Then you can just deposit new batch files (or EXE, or MSI, or any other) to update each application into that central location whenever new updates become available.

This batch file would essentially act as an "updater for the updaters" (option 3) but keeping it as simple and barebones as possible.

However, this is just my first take on it without knowing more about your problem. There are much better ways of doing it, especially if everything is on an internal company network (MSI deployments, infrastructure automation tools like Chef and Puppet, IT inventory tools that support bulk update pushes, etc); but the above is one potential way of implementing the whole thing in 15 minutes if that's what you need.

### Edit

Adding the comment to my answer...

The next best way I can think of is to create a C# project for the updater application itself (the .exe of the updater application), but put the updater's LOGIC into a separate .dll file which comes bundled with the updater. The updater can then dynamically load the .dll when it starts up, and if there's an update for the DLL itself - it can unload it, grab the new DLL, and then re-load it, all at run-time without anything noticeable to the user. All of the actual updater logic would live in the DLL and can be updated at-will by simply having the updater replace its own DLL...

Comment: No, its not a company network. Im using google docs as file deposit (free and I can store everything there), the users, well they are users. Its not a commercial product nor is it planned to be; the applications itself are small .exe (desktop applications without installer, just the .exe with a few ressource files).

Comment: Would an option work to just bundle a batch file with each application which would ping a URL (specific for that application) to see if there are updates available, and if yes, just download them and re-write the files with the new ones? It would be pretty easy to have the batch file replace as well. If this scheme would work for you I can update my answer with more details

Comment: I would prefer to have the updater in itself since it would be the easiest way to display additional informations for the other applications. (That information should be in the updater since the updater can function as an overview/ installer that way as well)

Comment: Then the next best way I can think of is to create a C# project for the updater application itself (the .exe of the updater application), but put the updater's LOGIC into a separate .dll file which comes bundled with the updater. The updater can then dynamically load the .dll when it starts up, and if there's an update for the DLL itself - it can unload it, grab the new DLL, and then re-load it, all at run-time without anything noticeable to the user. All of the actual updater logic would live in the DLL and can be updated at-will by simply having the updater replace its own DLL...

Comment: This is what i did in the end, it works fine. I agree that normally you shouldnt update an updater, but since it was/ is still a beta updater with almost daily changes (layout, logic) it would be a hassle to always grab a new version of it. If you would edit your answer with the comments content, I'll accept it. (Since I cant accept the comment itself)